# Adjoint spinors in Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, spinors

I am reading through Griffiths textbook "Introduction to Elementary Particles" and I am in the middle of the chapter on Quantum Electrodynamics and Feynman Rules for his diagrams.

There is one part that I am having a hard time understanding what the actual physical representation of the rule represents. (There are really more than one, but if I can just accept the virtual particles don't lie on the mass shell business for the time being and maybe ask more questions about that later when I can figure out what to even ask haha).

[image: Griffiths Feynman Rules]

Rule number 2 of the diagrams, Griffiths states that the outgoing electrons (and incoming positrons) add factors of the adjoint of the bi-spinors. What exactly does this represent? In normal QM you use the Hermitian conjugate to prove that an operator represents a physical variable with a real expectation value. Earlier in the book Griffiths says the adjoint of a spinor $\psi^*$ can multiply with the spinor $\psi$ and that value is invariant under transformations between inertial frames. And these things are all fine and dandy as far as mathematical formalism goes.

But when these rules in the Feynman diagram make it appear as though the result of an electron entering into an interaction of some sort with spinor $u$ comes out with spinor $\bar u$.

So here's my question. What does the adjoint operator physically represent as occurring here? Is the spin actually changing? Or is this still just necessary to stay mathematically consistent?

It may be useful to talk about it in terms of an example, so here is one from the book.

[[image: Griffiths Electron Muon Scattering2]

Griffiths uses the convention that time points upwards. And this is electron-muon scattering as indicated. So once again based off of the rule stated above, does the interaction actually change the spinor? Or is this just needed for the math to work out given linear algebra rules of vector and matrix math?

Comment: I am surprised Griffiths doesn’t explain this. Why don’t you read the relevant two chapters in Peskin & Schroeder, where it is very well explained how the $\bar u$ comes about.

Comment: *Does the interaction actually change the spinor?* In general, yes. The spin states of both the electron and muon can change due to their interaction, just like their momentum can change. The amplitude lets you calculate the probability that all these things change in a particular way, from particular momenta and spin states coming in, to particular other momenta and other spin states going out.

Comment: However, often in QED calculations, spin-state-averaging is done if one doesn’t actually care about the spin states. This is why you often see the final amplitude just expressed in terms of momenta.

Comment: when you say "change the spinor", do you mean change the spinor into an adjoint?